# Boot device options not including USB

Tags: boot, laptop, usb

For HP 255 G7 Notebook with Win7 64bit,

Needed to boot from USB in order to recover Win7 after lost password..
in the BOOT devices options after pressing ESC, the USB option was missing.

In the BOOT bios setup the USB marked as enabled

Please help !! how to return the option to boot from USB

Comment: Is the USB-Device plugged into your Notebook when you turn on your notebook (it should be)? Did you try another USB-Device?

Comment: What format does your USB drive have?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had the option to boot from USB on this laptop before?
It is possible that the BIOS can handle USB boot, but the laptop hardware cannot.  The BIOS firmware is often generic to a large range of hardware.

I have had desktop PCs like this.  BIOS said yes, but hardware said no. :(